# offline fb posting not working

Tags: php, facebook, offlineapps

I have to post on a users wall when he is offline. I went through number of posting and checked the code written below seems ok and also not throwing error and complete successful yet I am unable to see posting on users wall. Pl help.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(
                array(
                   'appId'  => "446262598768110",
                   'secret' => "<REMOVED>",
                )
            );


 $facebook->setAccessToken("<REMOVED>");
//create message with token gained before
echo " lets try posting";

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
echo "\ndone3..... $access_token.-----.$user_id.----new\n";


$post = array(
           'message' => 'This message is posted with access token - ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

//and make the request
$res = $facebook->api("/me/feed", 'GET', $post); //have tried both Post and Get method but result remain same
```

Comment: are you requesting the proper permission during authorization?

Comment: Trust yes, have set both offline_access and publish_stream as scope both in the app as well as in the code which in turn ask the user to authenticate and allow access..

Answer (score 0):

offline access was removed quite a few months ago. also, you do have to "POST" to facebook graph, everytime you want to publish something.

without seeing the result of the facebook graph, it's kind of impossible to help you at all.

nevertheless: double check, that you're using the correct access token. you have to extend the short lived access tokens by your own (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/), so that the access token itself is still valid when you want to post by cron-job.

if you're trying to post by using the app access token, you can't use "/me/feed" at all.

Comment: "without seeing the result of the facebook graph, it's kind of impossible to help you at all."  <---- how to get and share the graph

Comment: I have tested/verified again...I am getting the same access token which i am already having for the user since y'day. So trusting it is a long term valid token.

Comment: have you verified the access token with the access token debugger? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token

Comment: yes I had tested through this debugger too...and debugger says token is valid

Comment: do a print_r($res); after the facebook->api call and check the result.

Comment: when i print keeping the method "get" it gets completed without error and print success too [if($res){echo "success";}else{echo "Fail";}] ..... besides if I try to print $res it prints it to be an Array... strange thing is no posting take place on the wall..... At the same time if I use post method it throws error like OAuthException: (#368) The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed

Comment: when you do a print_r instead of a print, you get the complete content of the array instead of "Array".

Comment: I am getting following array content.... I am sorry not able to set in a readable format...... `Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100004694614107_158958120937341 [from] => Array ( [name] => Jimmy Smith [id] => 100004694614107 ) [story] => Jimmy Smith likes Developer Page and Facebook Developers. [story_tags] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 100004694614107 [name] => Jimmy Smith [offset] => 0 [length] => 11 [type] => user ) ) [18] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 367570586696665 [name] => Developer Page [offset] => 18 [length] => 15 [type] => page ) ) [38] =>....

Comment: I can see all except the post which i intended to make on his wall :(